# Blogdown not showing plots when building site to the website

Tags: r, blogdown

It seems I cannot display plots from the .rmd file when deploying through Netlify. By some reason, `blogdown::serve_site()`displays all the output correctly, but when publishing to website, it appears a ? sign when it should be each plot.

According to the blogdown documentation, the *_files/figure-html/ will be generated under within the `static` folder and so it is, buy when I execute `knitr::opts_chunk$get("fig.path")`, the output is `"figure/"`.

I cannot understand where the problem is, because if the `fig.path` where incorrect, the path containing the plots in the local directory will be wrong as well.

Installed `rmarkdown 1.10.11` and still not working.

On the other hand, the documentation states to set `uglyURLs` to `true` and not to ignore the `_files$` in the `config.toml`, but the pronblem still persists.

Any help will be appreciated.

PD. The theme I'm using is `ghostwriter`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: for `ghostwriter` theme there is a hidden `.gitignore` under `static` folder. Removing this file was the solution!

Comment: If you install the development version of **blogdown**, this issue should be gone ([I have patched it a couple of weeks ago](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/c43ad38480aacecd8a711bc3f618f8ecaa0beb2c)).